# Error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations OOP

Tags: c++, oop

```
Diagram *p[3];
p[0] = new Diagram;
p[1] = new Board;
p[2] = new Pacman;
```

I am declaring the pointer of base class globally, meanwhile i initialize the pointer with the derived classes, however it gives an error if i do it globally, but not when i declare the pointer in the Display() function.

```
clang++    -c -o game-release.o game-release.cpp
game-release.cpp:42:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
p[0] = new Diagram;
^
game-release.cpp:43:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
p[1] = new Board;
^
game-release.cpp:44:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
p[2] = new Pacman;
^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [game-release.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Which `Display()` function? Can you give some more context? Also, you might want to add the compiler error message.

Comment: @envu  clang++    -c -o game-release.o game-release.cpp
game-release.cpp:42:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
p[0] = new Diagram;
^
game-release.cpp:43:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
p[1] = new Board;
^
game-release.cpp:44:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
p[2] = new Pacman;
^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [game-release.o] Error 1

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output there. It enhances readability.

Comment: @envu Here it is Sir. I will really appreciate your suggestion. Moreover if we declare pointers individually, it works but why not with the base class pointer?

Comment: I can only hint on what the problem could be, as your code is not complete. Judging from the error message, it seems that the compiler thinks that you try to declare `p` in lines 42, 43 and 44. Thus, it did not see a declaration for `p` before. Can you provide additional context?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do assignments at global scope - you can only have declarations and definitions there.
This is why the compiler says "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations".
(To the compiler, `p[0] = new Diagram;` must be a declaration since it's at global scope.)

Assignments have to go in a function, as you've noticed.

You can *initialise* inline at the declaration though, like this:

```
Diagram *p[3] = { new Diagram, new Board, new Pacman };
```

Comment: Although this way of declaring global pointers is correct by why not the p[3],i.e, Pacman class(derived) does not provide the functions defined in the Pacman class? i write it like this p[2]-> ,but it doesnt allows functions of the derived class Pacman

Comment: @Shaan Because when you have a pointer to a `Diagram`, the compiler can't know that it points to a `Pacman`. Read the chapter on polymorphism in your book.

Answer (score 1):

While it is OK to declare and initialize variables in global scope, you cannot assign to such variables. This might become clearer when you remind yourself that global scope can only contain declarations. You either need to declare and initialize in one go

```
Diagram *p[3] = {new Diagram, new Board, new Pacman};
```

or call a dedicated function at runtime to assign the elements.